# How to select all the geographic POINTS within a Rectangle in Postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table USERS, this table has a column called `coordinates` of type `geography(point, 4326)`

I would like to construct a query to select all the coordinates within a rectangle.

These are the coordinates of each corner of the rectangle:

```
topRight: lat: 40.136910949186415 lng: -104.603574437409
topLeft: lat: 40.136910949186415 lng: -105.48495964571721
bottomRight: lat: 39.728134609342135 lng: -104.603574437409
bottomLeft: lat: 39.728134609342135 lng: -105.48495964571721
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM USERS
 WHERE ST_Intersects
     ( coordinates
     , ST_MakeEnvelope ( -105.48495964571721 -- xmin (min lng)
                       , 39.728134609342135 -- ymin (min lat)
                       , -104.603574437409 -- xmax (max lng)
                       , 40.136910949186415 -- ymax (max lat)
                       , 4326 -- projection epsg-code
                       )::geography('POLYGON') 
     )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).